# multipart from data iOS does this match the Android code?

Tags: ios

I am attempt to match some Android code for the iOS version. I can't get the Android code to build, but download the apt and it seems to work, I can't see anything at all in the server logs, nothing, nada, nil, zilch, and the server just times out on the request. I can however talk to the other end points successfully.

I am kind of stuck at this point. The backend server supported by neo4j.

With the image data is there a correct way of sending it???
I've tried as NSData hex string, directly from the file as the commented out code, I've tried NSData with Base64 encoding with(out) line breaks, and all variations there of.

Does the Android code match the iOS...? Noting that I've hacked about with it endlessly.

**The Android code:**

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.WebServiceEndPoints.IMAGE_ADD_URL);
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response;
    PostItemDto postItemDto = new PostItemDto();
    try {
        createFingerprint(postItem);
        File image = new File(postItem.binaryUri.getPath());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
        InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toByteArray(fis)), FILE_DATA);
        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        multipartEntity.addPart(FILE_DATA, isb);
        multipartEntity.addPart("apiKey", new StringBody(API_KEY));
        multipartEntity.addPart(LOGIN_ID, new StringBody(postItem.loginId));
        multipartEntity.addPart(TITLE, new StringBody(postItem.title));
        multipartEntity.addPart(DESCRIPTION, new StringBody(postItem.description));
        multipartEntity.addPart(POST_TYPE, new StringBody(String.valueOf(postItem.postType)));
        multipartEntity.addPart(RATING, new StringBody(String.valueOf(postItem.rating)));
        multipartEntity.addPart(LAT, new StringBody(String.valueOf(postItem.lat)));
        multipartEntity.addPart(LON, new StringBody(String.valueOf(postItem.lon)));
        multipartEntity.addPart(TIME, new StringBody(String.valueOf(postItem.time)));
        multipartEntity.addPart(FINGERPRINT, new StringBody(String.valueOf(postItem.fingerprint)));

        httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        final InputStream responseStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String responseString = IOUtils.toString(responseStream);
```

### The iOS code:

```
    [manager POST:serviceURL parameters:orderedDict  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
     {
         NSString *outputPostImageStr = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
         // [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:nameStr fileName:fileName mimeType:mimeTypeString ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:outputPostImageStr name:@"postImage" ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[orderedDict valueForKey:@"apiKey" ] name:@"apiKey" ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[NIL_TO_STRING(loginId) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"loginId"   ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[NIL_TO_STRING(post.title) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"title"  ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[NIL_TO_STRING(post.descriptionStr) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] name:@"description"  ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[NIL_TO_STRING(post.postType) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] name:@"postType"  ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[post.rating stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] name:@"rating"  ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:userLocation.coordinate.latitude]  stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] name:@"lat"  ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:userLocation.coordinate.longitude] stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] name:@"lon"  ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[self timeSince1970] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] name:@"time"  ];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[ [orderedDict valueForKey:@"fingerprint"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] name:@"fingerprint"  ];


     }
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         successBlock(YES);
     }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         [self showConnectionError];
         DLog(@"error: %@", error);
         errorBlock(error);
     }];
```

Comment: I see a start of a try block in your Android code; are you getting an exception by any chance?

Comment: thanks for the comment but no, I have a try/catch around the iOS code also.. And the catches log the heck the out of everything..

I think that there is some kind of undocumented black magic happening on the server side that only works with the Android version.

Its the Android code that is working the iOS just times out with no server log message, it just sits there waiting...

Comment: What, which version is working and which is not? Your original question is unclear. You might also try using an HTTP Proxy (like Charles Proxy) to see the request your apps are making and the responses from the server.